# Does a socket remain open even if one sides ip address changes?

Tags: sockets, java-7

If I open a socket between two computers on the WAN, while at least one of them has a dynamic ip-address, and this address changes even though the socket hasn't been explicitly closed : Do  have a warranty that this socket will remain open at least until my program really asks to close it?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as the IP address of one of the two computers changes then the computer that held on to the original address, (not knowing the new address) would no longer be able to communicate with the other.  There is no automatic process of informing the connected clients that a new IP address has been assigned, you could conceivably create one but you would have to communicate the new address over the old IP address before you changed it.  Also the other computer wouldn't immediately know that addresses had changed at all, you would have to wait until it timed out.  The other big challenge is the likelihood that the computer wouldn't even know that it's own IP address had changed because on a WAN it might be exposed to the internet via a NATed addresses.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I just would like a kind of channel in order to communicate (from time to time) simple pairs of chess cell coordinates. E.g (3,0,2,6). So is there a good alternative to the direct communication via Sockets ? Regards

Comment: The way Skype does (or so I've read) this is to have a central server that keeps tabs on people's IP addresses, so when a connection is dropped due to a network reconfiguration the client can go back to that central database and see if there is updated information. This is an interesting shallow dive into it: http://www.mjalali.com/blog/?p=10